# How can I run JavaScript snippets in Chrome when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to test some JavaScript locally and would like it to run on page load. The problem is that when I create a new snippet, I need to manually run it for it to take effect. I would like it to run without me doing anything including when I refresh the page.

Comment: sounds like tampermonkey may be what you want

Comment: There are also simpler extensions for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

In the body tag of the html document, call your JavaScript function ... body onload="myFunction()" within the angle brackets, of course

Comment: Wouldn't I need to edit the source file for this? I would like to do so without the need to.

Comment: Yes.  I thought you were working on your own scripts and wanted them to run without having to hit a button on your page, so as to just reload the page and have the script get fired.